# Nested for loop not correctly executed

Tags: python

I started with the following:

```
auth = steelhead.CLIAuth(username=args.username, password=args.password)
sh = steelhead.SteelHead(host=192.168.1.2, auth=auth)
f = open('commands.txt')
for command in f:
    print sh.cli.exec_command(command)
f.close()
```

This worked perfectly fine. I have two commands in commands.txt and I gut the result of both back.

Next, I wanted to implement an ip.txt, where the user can put all IP's of all machines where we want to run the commands in commands.txt.

I tried this:

```
h = open('appliances.txt')
for appliance in h:
    auth = steelhead.CLIAuth(username=args.username, password=args.password)
    sh = steelhead.SteelHead(host=appliance, auth=auth)

    f = open('commands.txt')
    for command in f:
        print sh.cli.exec_command(command)
    f.close()
h.close()
```

I have only one IP in appliances.txt, but I expected to see the output of the two commands in commands.txt just as I did before adding the appliances.txt loop.

Unfortunately I only see the output of the first command in commands.txt, the seconds seems to get not executed.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the loops; perhaps the newline at the end of `appliance` (there will almost certainly be one there) makes a difference here?

Comment: You are opening 'appliances.txt'. Did you mean to open 'ip.txt'?

Comment: Also, `host=192.168.1.2` is not valid Python syntax; are there quotes missing there?

Comment: Also, opening 'commands.txt' for each remote is not needed. You could open each file once outside the loops which would remove the extra open and closes.

Comment: thanks to all. I have no idea what I changed, but it's working now (code still looks the same).